# Does anyone know what would cause this?

Tags: troubleshooting, adhesion, geeetech

I’m a 3D printing newbie. I’ve tried adjusting various settings but nothing seems to help.  Most of the brim looks great and I’m pretty sure my bed is level, but as soon as it starts printing the actual model parts of it don’t stick and ends up in clumps.

[image: Close up of print]

[image: Resulting print]

Comment: Hello Skittles9654, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Your question is very terse and hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading < and trailing > afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: What is the material? Is the bed heater working? What is the material covering the bed?

Comment: When was the last time you cleaned your bed?